# Are Noachides/Non-Jews encouraged/expected to do maaser kesafim?

Tags: gentiles, money, tzedakah-charity, noachide-laws, maaser-tithes

A friend of mines has been infatuated by Judaism for as long as I can remember. He came from the Christian world and has since left it. Even as a Christian he would take 10% of his income and give to local charities. He also would use this money to buy seforim for himself and others for learning.

So are Non-Jews/Noahides expected or encouraged to do maaser kesafim (setting aside 10% of take home income)? 
And what can/should the monies go to?

Comment: Maaser is a mitzvah specific for Jews but tzedakah as a general action is definitely positive for non Jews to do

Comment: Maa'ser goes to a Cohen. As I understand it, it is one of the Cohen's gifts from Jews, specifically. If a Gentile gave a Cohen 1/10 of his produce / income, etc. I don't think that's called *ma'aser*.

Comment: @DanF I believe _ma'aser_ is given to the L'viyim, the poor, and oneself ([e.g.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_tithe)).

Comment: @DanF also it applies to a non-Jew's produce (Demai 5:9), he's just allowed to eat it without taking it off.  And if he takes terumah or maaser, it takes full effect (Terumos 3:9)